# Keep form values that were changed via Javascript after submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I've got a form with a `<select>` option that changes the value of another `<select>` option in the form. This works fine when someone submits the form and the form is valid. When the form is invalid, however, it loads the original value of the `<select>` option.

What is causing this and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Without seeing any code it's difficult to say

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code I would imagine that in the case of invalid forms you have a function that is validating the input prior to submission? If this is the case then perhaps the submit button is still refreshing page without sending the data to the server? maybe a click event with e.preventDefault() would solve this for you.